# MySQL not selecting row with given id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, a 'climates' table and a 'favourablecrops' table. I want to select all the favourable crops for a particular location using this query but it just selects everything regardless of the specified 'id'

```
SELECT tbl_climatic.location, tbl_favourablecrops.favCrop 
FROM tbl_climatic, 
     tbl_favourablecrops 
WHERE tbl_climatic._id=tbl_favourablecrops.location_id=0
```

Kindly assist

Comment: Is that a valid sql syntax.

Comment: You can't do `WHERE \`col1\` = \`col2\` = value`.  Use `WHERE tbl_climatic._id=tbl_favourablecrops.location_id AND tbl_climatic._id = 0`

Comment: Please include table structure and sample data.  Your WHERE also doesn't make sense, as it's saying X=Y=0

Comment: @JenR: `X=Y=0` is syntactically valid, albeit probably not what the OP intended.

Comment: thanks for that correction, learning it each new day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a standard `join` with appropriate `where` criteria:

```
SELECT tbl_climatic.location, tbl_favourablecrops.favCrop 
FROM tbl_climatic join
     tbl_favourablecrops on tbl_climatic._id=tbl_favourablecrops.location_id
WHERE tbl_favourablecrops.location_id=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You trying to combine `join` condition and `filter` condition. Use proper `INNER JOIN` and keep the `JOIN` condition `ON` clause and move the filters to `where` clause

May be this what you are looking for.

```
SELECT tbl_climatic.location,
       tbl_favourablecrops.favCrop
FROM   tbl_climatic
       INNER JOIN tbl_favourablecrops
               ON tbl_climatic._id = tbl_favourablecrops._id
WHERE  tbl_favourablecrops.location_id = 0
```

Comment: Nice timing...  Feels familiar to a previous post -- this one confirms a consensus a little better than the other though ;)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have real boolean types—instead it uses `0` for false and `1` for true. (Even if it *did* have real booleans, it [automatically casts values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html) based on the expression in which they are used anyway—so it wouldn't make any difference).

`A=B=0` is parsed as `(A=B)=0`.  Thus, the expression reduces to `A<>B`.

Therefore you are *not* filtering, as you had imagined, for only those records where both `tbl_climatic._id` and `tbl_favourablecrops.location_id` are zero.

You need to perform separate comparisons:

```
WHERE tbl_climatic._id = 0
  AND tbl_favourablecrops.location_id = 0
```

However, as others have pointed out, it's good practice to get in the habit of using explicit joins—they can help to avoid a great many pitfalls.