# What's MySQL's string compare rule?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Why does `SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='a'='mm';` actually return rows?

And why doesn't `SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='1'='1';` work?

What's the exact equal operator compare rule used?

**UPDATE(INFORMATION OF TABLES AND ROWS ETC):**

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_shengy |
+------------------+
| users            |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+----------+----------+
| username | password |
+----------+----------+
| victim   | 123456   |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28951037

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL converts compares to `0` and `1`.

So `password='a'` evaluates to `0` (unless `password` actually *is* `'a'`).

Also MySQL tries to make comparisons between strings and numbers by converting the string to a number from its beginning.

So `0abc` would be converted to `0`. `abc` isn't a number at all and is also `0`.

That means

```
password='a'='mm'
```

results in

```
0='mm'
```

and since `mm` does not have any leading digits, you get

```
0=0
```

which is true.

Comment: But my password does not start with 0, you can see it's actually 123456, and it's type is varchar(255)

Comment: @shengy: because `=` is left-associative, your statement is actually parsed as `WHERE (password='a')='mm'`; and since `password='a'` is false, the expression becomes `WHERE 0='mm'`.  Finally, because casting `'mm'` to an integer (i.e. attempting to take leading digits, but finding none) yields `0`, the comparison succeeds.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks:) but the relevant link you posted seems to say `=` is right-associative: `A=B=0 is parsed as A=(B=0)`

Comment: @shengy: Yes—I wrote that answer (now updated), under the same misunderstanding (that `=` is right-associative) as juergen presumably had when he wrote his answer above.

Comment: @eggyal Can you post an answer here so I can accept it?